# React-native-tab-view: On tapping on tabs transition is very slow but on swipe it is very smooth

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-tab-view

I am using [react-native-tab-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tab-view) for the tabs but when I am clicking on tabs transition is very slow. And on swipe it is smooth and fast.
What I did to resolve it:-
I make all sub component a PureComponent which is being rendered on index change. That means it will not re-render if content is not different from previous. And I crossed checked if components is being re-rendered or not and components are not re-rendering.
But still it lagging or slow transition if click on tabs(not on swipe)

Comment: I am facing same problem, did you find any solution of this issue ?

Comment: Buddy.. u have to optimize your code. It should not be rendered again once it is rendered. I optimized my code then it is solved. Use PureComponent or shouldComponentUpdate in your components

Comment: yes. i did this and worked for me as well

Comment: @ShankarMorwal I agree that you handled through PureComponents but why it was working fine when scrolling ? Any thoughts ?

Comment: @ankitjaiswal - Was you able to fix this issue?

Comment: Yeah, Actually you need to optimize the code. For each component use "extends PureComponents" or for functional component use "React.memo" that's how you can optimize it.

Comment: I haveadded but I can see any impact. In my page, I have about 9 tabs and each tab has data containing 8=9 items.

Comment: The only reason of its slowdown or lag is multiple rendering all the items in all 9 tabs. Try printing console.log() you will see whenever you change the tab all the items gets printed. To resolve this I think separate each and every component (tabs components). Use PureComponent in list items not in the whole tab.

Comment: this is happening to me when I use `lazy: true` props. has anyone resolved the issue ?